# Understanding the Number Line through Convexity

Tags: convex-analysis, real-numbers, integers

I came across the following picture:

[image]

According to this picture, it would appear that Natural Numbers, Integers, Rational Numbers and Real Algebraic Numbers are all Non-Convex sets - but Real Numbers are Convex.

For instance, if you take the set of integers - it is impossible to "go from" the number 2 and "reach" the number 2.1 without remaining within the set of integers : This makes me think of integers as Non-Convex. However, if you consider the set of real numbers, it seems like you can go from any element to any other element in the set - thus making the set of real numbers as Convex.

- Is this interpretation correct?

For some reason, I think my interpretation is not correct. If my interpretation were correct - this would mean that it would be impossible to have a "Convex Hull" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull) over any set of integers.

For example, Discrete Optimization Problems are over the set of integers, the set of integers are non-convex - yet a Convex Hull can still be defined for such problems (e.g. [https://www2.isye.gatech.edu/~mgoetsch/cali/VEHICLE/TSP/TSP017__.HTM](https://www2.isye.gatech.edu/%7Emgoetsch/cali/VEHICLE/TSP/TSP017__.HTM)). As I understand, a Convex Hull is the biggest Convex Set contained within an otherwise Non-Convex set.

(*For some reason, identifying the Convex Hull in Optimization Problems is said to be important, but I don't quite understand why identifying the Convex Hull is important - for example, in problems like the Travelling Salesman ... why would identifying the Convex Hull be important?*)

How is this then possible?

- In the above picture, are all sets of numbers "Non-Convex" except the Real Numbers?
- How is it possible to have a Convex Hull within the sets of Integers that contains more than one integer? Since we can not "reach" any integer from any other integer without leaving the set of integers - how can a Convex Hull within the set of integers contain more than a single element?

For instance, over the set of integers (a Non-Convex set) - suppose for a specific optimization problem we identified a Convex Hull containing the elements (-2,-1,0,1,2) : Within this Convex Hull, we can not go from -2 to -1.9, thus violating the definition of Convexity. It would appear as though in this case, the Convex Hull itself is Non-Convex.

Can someone please help me better understand this?

Thank you!

Comment: There is no convex analysis involved here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on your notion of "convex set". Typically, a set $C \subset \mathbb R$ is defined to be a convex set, if
$$
\lambda a + (1-\lambda) b \in C$$
holds for all $a,b \in C$ and all $\lambda \in (0,1) := \{ \mu \in \mathbb R \mid 0 < \mu < 1\}$.
That is, the definition of "convex" needs the knowledge of real numbers.

Let us pretend, that we only now the rational numbers $\mathbb Q$. Then, the convexity of a set $C \subset \mathbb Q$ could be defined via
$$
\lambda a + (1-\lambda) b \in C \qquad\forall a,b \in C, \lambda \in \{ \mu \in \mathbb Q \mid 0 < \mu < 1\}.$$
Suddenly, $\mathbb Q$ becomes a convex set...

Answer (score 2):

You've got it backward: a set's convex hull is a *superset* of the given set, not a subset. Thus, the convex hull of the set of integers is the real line.